# How to save data in MongoDB with one-to-many relations?

Tags: mongodb

I need to save texts which are split into statements (can be 5 or 5000 statements) and I'm thinking about a way to do it in MongoDB for maximum performance.

Right now I simply write every text (with all the statements) into the `texts' collection of MongoDB. I create a property` statement`in the text document where I write all the statements as an array (with an`id`assigned in my Node.Js app via`uuid.v1`).

So the data looks like this:

```json
{"_id":{"$oid":"61548955c1bc78934cc3ef10"},
"statements":
 [
  {"content":"stop thinking ideas and bring stop thinking and decide ", "id":"ID1"},
  {"content":" stop thinking ", "id":"ID2"},
  {"content":" orange apple", "id":"ID3"}
 ],
"user":{"$oid":"61536842a8097fbad18fe633"},
"contextName":"lokhead","__v":0}
```

There is also another option: to create a separate collection for `statements` and to write the statements with the right context id to that collection.

So there are 3 options and I wanted to ask your advice on the best one in terms of performance:

1. Write all the statements into the `text` document directly
2. Create a new collection `statements` and write the statements there with the related `context.id`
3. Create a new collection `statements` and write the statements there, while creating a one-to-many relation in the `texts` collection document, which lists all the IDs of the statements added into the DB.

What would the most efficient way with the best data structure?